# How to create a python function that checks a website's availability?

Tags: python, function

My code I have currently wrote is as follows:

```
def Ws_availbality(url):
    check = print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/").getcode())
    if check == 200:
        print ("Website is running")
    else:
        print("The website is currently down")

Ws_availbality('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

---

The issue is though it returns 200 I cannot get the if statement to execute. It simply executes the else statement. I am also open to different function approaches.

Comment: `print` returns `None`, so `check` is `None`.

Comment: What does `print()` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your print elsewhere:

```
def Ws_availbality(url):
    check = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/").getcode()
    print(check)
    if check == 200:
        print ("Website is running")
    else:
        print("The website is currently down")

Ws_availbality('https://www.youtube.com/')
```